# What is the best way to place a custom code after an action in php in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

This is the admin piece of my code of plugin:

```php
function dbi_plugin_section_text() {
    echo '<p>Saisir le taux de conversion pour le prix d\'achat USD=>EUR en pourcentage</p>';
}
function dbi_plugin_setting_rate() {
    $options = get_option( 'dbi_example_plugin_options' );
    echo "<input id='dbi_plugin_setting_rate' name='dbi_example_plugin_options[pctrate]' type='text' value='" . (($options !== false) ? esc_attr( $options['pctrate'] ) : '' ). "' />";
}

function dbi_register_settings() {
    register_setting( 'dbi_example_plugin_options', 'dbi_example_plugin_options', 'dbi_example_plugin_options_validate' );
    add_settings_section( 'pctrate', 'Réglages du taux', 'dbi_plugin_section_text', 'dbi_example_plugin' );

    add_settings_field( 'dbi_plugin_setting_rate', 'Taux (%) EUR/USD', 'dbi_plugin_setting_rate', 'dbi_example_plugin', 'pctrate' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'dbi_register_settings' );

  function load_awesome_plugin_page() 
{ 
    ?>
    <h2>Manage buy and sell prices</h2>
    <form action="options.php" method="post">
        <?php 
        settings_fields( 'dbi_example_plugin_options' );
        do_settings_sections( 'dbi_example_plugin' ); ?>
        <input name="submit" class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save' ); ?>" />
        <input type="submit" onlick="event.preventDefault();" value="Modifier les prix de venrte de chaque produit en utilisant le taux saisi ci-dessus" />
    </form>
    <?php
}

 function register_rate() {
    add_menu_page
    ( 
        'Manage Buy & Sell rates', 
        'Manage Buy & Sell rates', 
        'edit_posts', 
        'manage_rates', 
        'load_awesome_plugin_page', 
        'dashicons-media-spreadsheet' 
       );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_rate' );
```

It works as expected to store a value on database when I submit the form

Good.

Now, I want to add another button that do that thing :
[functionnality to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0bAK.png)

Make an HTTP request to pass over each product in php in wordpress and change the price

What is the path of http request in a wordpress world nomenclature to be called ?
like /wp-ajax/mycode.php and then I call it in my rounded black button on screen ?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 1):

Defining AJAX functions in WordPress is quite simple, first you have to declare your PHP callback:

```
function your_ajax_callback() {
    
    // Do whatever you need here
    
    echo "Your response";
    
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_ajax_callback', 'your_ajax_callback' );
```

And then in JavaScript pass the action name to the AJAX request:

```
var data = {
        'action': 'your_ajax_callback'
};

jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

});
```

Note that the `ajaxurl` variable is generated by WordPress and is always available in the admin screens. Usually it just points to `/admin-ajax.php`.